# Recurrence calculator

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on a C# application that relies heavily on recurring events. Following kinds of recurrence are supported:

1. Daily recurrence
2. Weekly recurrence
3. Monthly recurrence

Basically, the application supports all the different combination of recurrences as supported by MS Outlook.

The problem:

The individual occurrence as calculated by the system for a recurring event does not consider the daylight savings and as a result the occurrence date time is displaying wrongly by the system. Is there a standard library or third party module available that can handle recurrence date calculations? Basically I want an API in the below format.

```
List<Occurence> GetAllOccurences(DateTime startTimeInUTC, DateTime EndTimeInUTC,    TimeZone targetTimeZone)

class Occurrence
{
    DateTime OccurenceStartDateTime {get;set;}
    DateTime OccurenceEndDateTime {get;set;}
}
```

Is such an API available? It could make my life much easier.

Comment: Is anything from [Recurrence Library for date calculations for .Net](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4517376/706456) useful? Also worth looking at [these tests](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/source/browse/src/NodaTime.Test/TimeZones/ZoneRecurrenceTest.cs?r=1bb28d469d4c3a7913a202b485c1ac16e25c6601) for Noda-time.

Answer (score 1):

This may help [Task Scheduler](http://taskschedulerengine.codeplex.com/)  Or search for Cron libraries, there are a couple of different ones and one of them should do as you wish.