# Mysql reccuring dates

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I'm working on reservation sistem for sport halls.
Administrator can choose start and end date of reservation via daterangepicker.

Example:

```
start datetime: 2015-08-12 14:00:00
end datetime: 2015-08-12 16:00:00
```

This create reservation for specific sport object on that day and time.

Now what i want to do is when user check checkbox(reservate for whole year) this insert reservation for whole year.(from start date increase date +7)

Example:

```
2015-08-12 14:00:00      2015-08-12 16:00:00
2015-08-19 14:00:00      2015-08-19 16:00:00 
2015-08-26 14:00:00      2015-08-26 16:00:00
```

... for the whole year(till august of next year)

Comment: what's the question? Date + 7 isn't a year

Comment: This is not trivial to do good. See [Recurrence Library for date calculations for .Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517376/recurrence-library-for-date-calculations-for-net) for some libraries that can help you.

Comment: User select start and end of reservation. Example (start date)2015-08-12 14:00:00     (end date) 2015-08-12 16:00:00 now i want to know how to increase date(2015-08-12,2015-08-19,2015-08-26,2015-09-02...)