# How to calculate end date in the SQL with below RRULE

Tags: c#, sql

I need to calculate the end date of RRULE :

Weekly on Tuesday and Thursday for 5 weeks:

DTSTART;TZID=US-Eastern:19970902T090000
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=19971007T000000Z;WKST=SU;BYDAY=TU,TH
or
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT=10;WKST=SU;BYDAY=TU,TH

==> (1997 9:00 AM EDT)September 2,4,9,11,16,18,23,25,30;October 2

I need to do it in ms SQL. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The details you shared does not explain any thing. Can you share some sample input and expected output for them? Also explain the logic of generating the output? Can you also share whatever code you have written and tell us what exact issue you are facing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recurrence Library for date calculations for .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517376/recurrence-library-for-date-calculations-for-net)

Comment: For example: 

Start Date = 17-07-2020

Meeting Occurrence = 31(Monday to Friday)(Day calculation :Day Value
Monday 1
Tuesday 2
Wednesday 4
Thursday 8
Friday 16
Saturday 32
Sunday 64)

Count: 2

So send end date should be: 20-07-2020
Expected result = 20-07-2020

If count = 3 

So send end date should be: 21-07-2020
Expected result = 21-07-2020

I hope from this you will get some idea. Let me know if you need more information.

Thanks,

Comment: Hello @MurrayFoxcroft,

Thanks for sharing the details.

I need to implement it in SQL, I mentioned it c# because if I get logic from c# then I can convert it into the SQL.

Thanks,
Pankaj Kadian

Comment: The end date of RRULE is in the UNTIL=19971007T000000Z... Note that it may also have no end date.

Answer (score 0):

See following :

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2020, 7,17);

DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = date.DayOfWeek;

int addOffset = 0;
//get first tuesday or thursday
switch (dayOfWeek)
{
    case DayOfWeek.Sunday :
        addOffset = 2;
        break;
    case DayOfWeek.Monday:
        addOffset = 1;
        break;
    case DayOfWeek.Tuesday:
        addOffset = 0;
        break;
    case DayOfWeek.Wednesday:
        addOffset = 1;
        break;
    case DayOfWeek.Thursday:
        addOffset = 0;
        break;
    case DayOfWeek.Friday:
        addOffset = 4;
        break;
    case DayOfWeek.Saturday:
        addOffset = 3;
        break;
}
DateTime startDate = date.AddDays(addOffset);
DateTime currentDate = startDate;

int numberOfWeeks = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfWeeks; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(currentDate);
        if (currentDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Tuesday)
        {
            currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(2);
        }
        else
        {
            currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(5); //from thursday to tuesday
        }
    }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```